# Lower bound in $L^2([0,1])$ for the derivative under the constraint $f(x)\ge\sqrt x$ for $x\ge \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f\in C([0,1]) \cap C^1(0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$. Furthermore, let $1>\varepsilon>0$ and suppose that $f(x)\geq \sqrt{x}$ for $x\in [\varepsilon, 1]$.

I would like to show that $\int_0^1 (f'(y))^2 dy\geq c\cdot |\ln\varepsilon|$ for some constant $c>0$.

I expect that the minimizer of the functional $I(f)=\int_0^1 (f'(y))^2dy$ for $f\in H^1(0,1)$ with respect to the above constraints is given by
\begin{align}
g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \qquad \text{for }x\in[0,\varepsilon]\\
\sqrt{x}\qquad \text{for }x\in[\varepsilon,1],
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which obviously satisfies the required bound. This is most easily seen by drawing a picture and observing that one can decrease the value of the functional if the function lies above $g$ for some point $x\in[0,1]$.

Since I need to generalise this to a similar $2D$-problem, where this line of reasoning is more difficult, I hope someone can provide a simple analytical proof using only some basic calculus tools.

Comment: I would try something along the following lines $$ \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \leq \frac{f(\varepsilon)^2}{2} = \int_0^\varepsilon f'(x) f(x) dx \leq \left( \int_0^\varepsilon f(x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^\varepsilon (f'(x))^2 \right)^{1/2}. $$ Then you only need to find a suitable upper bound for $\int_0^\varepsilon f(x)^2 dx$. For this I would define $$ x_0 := \min \{ x\in [0,1] \ : f(x)=1 \}. $$ Then we can estimate $\int_0^{x_0} f(x)^2 dx \leq 1$.Thus, we only need to estimate $\int_{x_0}^1 f(x)^2 dx$.

Comment: Let me pretend for a second that we would know that there exists a minimizer $f$. Then we have for all $g\in C([x_0,1]) \cap C^1([x_0,1))$ with $g(x_0)=1$ and $g'(x_0) = f'(x_0)$ the functional $$ F(t) = \int_{x_0}^1 \left(  (1-t) f'(x) + t g'(t) \right)^2 dx$$ and we get $0= F'(0)= -2 \int_{x_0}^1 f'(x)^2 dx +2 \int_{x_0}^1 f'(x) g'(x) dx.$ Then we would get $$ \int_{x_0}^1 f'(x)^2 dx \leq  2 \int_{x_0}^1 (g'(x))^2 dx.  $$ In particular this would hold for $g_n(x) = 1+(1-n^{-1} e^{f'(x_0)n(x-x_0)})$, and so we could make $n$ large and get a nice upper bound (in fact $f'$ would vanish there).

Comment: Playing a bit with the functional, we should be able to get the correct sign for the derivative and then redo the argument above. Anyway, that is all just happy guessing on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Concerning your first comment, I don't really see how this estimate proves the logarithmic lower bound? Assuming that I can prove a good bound for $\int_0^\varepsilon f(x)^2dx$, how can you deduce $\int_0^1 (f'(y))^2dy\geq c|\ln \varepsilon|$ from that?

Comment: Concerning your second comment, I am also not sure whether I can follow your argument. If we agree for a second that the function $g$ in my question is the minimizer,  then you cannot conclude in general that $F'(0)=0$. The problem is that if you consider any function $\tilde{g}$ as described in your comment, then in general the family of functions $g+t\cdot (\tilde{g}-g)$ will not satisfy the constraints for $t\in (-\delta, \delta)$ for any small $\delta$. (Just consider a positive function, then you can only take positive $t$ but for negative $t$ the sum will not satisfy the constraints)

Comment: The constraints are not an issue. As $f(x_0)=1$, we can assume $f'(x_0)>0$ (otherwise we just extend by $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [x_0,1]$). Also, by the same reason, $f$ is increasing on $[x_0,1]$, thus we have enough room to wiggle a bit. The real issue is that the bound I gave is not good enough.

Comment: Maybe it is more promising to estimate $$ \ln(f(1)) - \ln(f(\varepsilon)) = \int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx \leq \left(\int_\varepsilon^1 f'(x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{1}{f(x)^2} dx \right)^{1/2} \leq  \left( \int_\varepsilon^1 f'(x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( - \ln(\varepsilon)\right)^{1/2}.$$ I guess we can similarly as I commented above show that $f(1)=1$, then we would need to show that $-\ln(f(\varepsilon))\geq -c \ln(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Dear Severin, there is no way of showing that $|\ln(f(\varepsilon))|\geq c|\ln(\varepsilon)|$, because $f(\varepsilon)=1$ is of course possible. (we could just interpolate from $0$ to $1$ on the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$.
For the same reason we cannot hope for an estimate of the type $\int_\varepsilon^1(f'(x))^2dx\geq c|\ln(\varepsilon)|$, since the function could increase on the interval $[0,\varepsilon)$ and be constant on the interval $[\varepsilon,1]$.

Comment: Of course that will not be true for a generic function. However, we don't care for such a generic function. It must only be true for functions sufficiently close to the minimum.

Comment: I totally agree but it's still not possible to show $-\ln(f(\varepsilon))\geq -c\ln(\varepsilon)$ for a function close to the minimum as this would imply $\ln(f(\varepsilon))\leq c\ln(\varepsilon)$ and therefore $f(\varepsilon)\leq \tilde{c}\varepsilon$, which contradicts $f(\varepsilon)\geq \sqrt{\varepsilon}$. I guess the problem with your second approach is that you never used the fact that $f(0)=0$, which is crucial for the statement to hold.

Comment: Not quite, it would imply $f(\varepsilon)\leq \varepsilon^c$, which does not contradict the assumption for $c<1/2$. And yes, sure, we need to use $f(0)=0$ to get a bound like that. I just don't see how :)

Comment: Oh sorry, my (embarassing) mistake! Anyway, thanks for your suggestions, I will try if I can use them somehow!

Comment: It is not embarassing! It happens to all of us. I would be very curious to see a solution to that problem. In case you figure it out, I'd love to know how it works. Unfortunately, I have no real idea how to turn this hand-waving comments above into an actual proof :(

Comment: @Jake28 In your question: "This is most easily seen". What are you talking about here?

Comment: @mathworker21 What I mean is that if you have a point on the function $f$ that lies above the function $g$, then you can draw a tangent to the function $g$ that runs through this point and meets the graph of $f$ at some other point. Then you can modify the function $f$ by replacing it's graph between the two points by this straight line segment and the value of the functional corresponding to the modified function is smaller, since we know that the straight line minimizes the functional if the endpoints are fixed and there are no constraints.

Comment: This is of course a bit hand wavy, but as mentioned in the question, I need to generalize this to a slightly more complicated problem in two dimensions and therefore I would like to have a more "analytic" proof as I have no idea how to make this one rigorous in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hardest" $\epsilon \in [0,1)$ to take will be such that $f(\epsilon) \le \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Letting $g(x) := f(x)-\sqrt{x}$, we have $\int_\epsilon^1 f'(x)^2dx = \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{4x}dx+\int_\epsilon^1 g'(x)^2dx + \int_\epsilon^1 g'(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. The first term is what you want, the second is clearly non-negative, and, by integration by parts, the third is $g(1)-g(\epsilon)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_\epsilon^1 x^{-3/2}g(x)dx$, which is non-negative.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Would you mind to elaborate a little bit on why we can assume $f(\varepsilon)=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$? I agree, of course, that a larger value will make things worse, but it would be nice to have a rigorous argument. 
Remark: Your argument shows more generally, that if $f(\varepsilon)=h(\varepsilon)$, $f\geq h$, $h'\geq 0$ and $h''\leq 0$ (for $x\in[\varepsilon,1]$), then $\int_\varepsilon^1 (f'(x))^2dx\geq \int_\varepsilon^1(h'(x))^2dx$.

Comment: I just realized that the general case follows by a simple adaption of your argument, so thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Jake28 No problem. By "general case", do you mean the 2D version you were really after? If not, I can try to explain the $f(\epsilon) \le \sqrt{\epsilon}$ assumption more.

Comment: No, I meant the case that $f(\varepsilon)>\sqrt{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: @Jake28 Note I did not say $f(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon}$. I allow $\epsilon = 0$. If $f(\epsilon) > \sqrt{\epsilon}$, we can decrease until $f(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ or until $\epsilon = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @Jake28 In any event, it seems we've figured everything out. Nice question!

Comment: There is no issue. It's just that in my head $\varepsilon$ was a fixed number between $(0,1)$, but your argument is totally fine so never mind!